# how to add attribute and add class in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to add attribute and add class in react js.I am trying to create `TABS` using react.I want to add `hidden` class when `Tab` element width is more the `45px` and new attribute `aria-hidden` with value `true` .
can you please tell me how to do this ?

**component**

```
<Tabs>
      {data.map((i, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{i}</li>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
```

**Tabs.js**

```
 const getTabs = () => {
    console.log("get tabs");
    const { blockWidth, tabsTotalWidth, tabDimensions, showMoreWidth } = state;

    let tabIndex = 0;
    let availableWidth = blockWidth - showMoreWidth;
    return children.reduce(
      (result, tabItem, index, arr) => {
        const { key = index } = tabItem.props;
        const tabWidth = tabDimensions[key] ? tabDimensions[key].width : 0;

        if (tabWidth < 45) {
          //  aria-hidden= false
          // remove hidden class tabItem if present.
          result.tabsVisible.push(tabItem);
        } else {
          //  aria-hidden= true
          // add hidden class tabItem
          result.tabsHidden.push(tabItem);
        }
        /* eslint-enable no-param-reassign */

        availableWidth -= tabWidth;
        return result;
      },
      {
        tabsVisible: [],
        tabsHidden: []
      }
    );
  };
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hermann-yt7es?file=/src/tabs.js:2147-2486

I am rendering tab like this

```
return (
     <ul ref={tabsRef} className="rc64nav">
          {/* {children} */}
          {tabsVisible.reduce((result, tabItem, tabIndex) => {
            result.push(tabItem);
            return result;
          }, [])}
    
          {tabsHidden.reduce((result, tabItem, tabIndex) => {
            result.push(tabItem);
            return result;
          }, [])}
        </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

For classes, you can simply add the className attribute. You can add attributes exactly the same as HTML elements.

Comment: Then how can you add class to a react component? Can you show me right answer?